# C++ Not letting me use other constructor in initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I'm trying to have a constructor call other constructors in their initialization list for I don't have duplicate logic.  Here is what my .h file looks like:

```
class Button : public Component
{
public:
    Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, string normalSrc, string hoverSrc, string downSrc);
    Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, string normalSrc, string hoverSrc, string downSrc, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b);
    Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, string src) : Button(x, y, width, height, src, src, src) { }
    Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, string src, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b) : Button(x, y, width, height, src, src, src, r, g, b) { }
    ~Button();
```

but when I try to compile (using -std=c++0x as an extra compiler flag) I get this error:

```
In file included from /home/villages/Desktop/ogam-january-pipes/src/Vesper/Ui/Button.cpp:8:0:
/home/villages/Desktop/ogam-january-pipes/src/Vesper/Ui/Button.h: In constructor ‘Button::Button(int, int, int, int, std::string)’:
/home/villages/Desktop/ogam-january-pipes/src/Vesper/Ui/Button.h:29:60: error: type ‘Button’ is not a direct base of ‘Button’
/home/villages/Desktop/ogam-january-pipes/src/Vesper/Ui/Button.h: In constructor ‘Button::Button(int, int, int, int, std::string, Uint8, Uint8, Uint8)’:
/home/villages/Desktop/ogam-january-pipes/src/Vesper/Ui/Button.h:30:87: error: type ‘Button’ is not a direct base of ‘Button’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Villages.dir/src/Vesper/Ui/Button.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Villages.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your compiler doesn't support delegating constructors yet? You need something like GCC 4.9 or MSVC13.

Comment: What compiler are you using? It is possible your compiler (or the version you have) does not support delegating constructors (this is indeed a C++11 feature).

Comment: OT: For Heaven's sake, man, `const string&` for those params. there is enough needless string copying in code these days as it is.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Eh, no, as-is there could be _moves_, not copies; all that's missing here is some `std::move` calls in the initialization lists. See [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: @ildjarn After reading that article (and I had to sit down with some booze to get through the comments) I've pretty impressed with the idea, and may take it to heart by virtue of SFINAE and "std::enable_if<std::is_move_constructible<T>>" At least I *think* that would work. Thanks for the tip. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using the wrong compiler/version. The *delegating constructors* feature is a *C++11* feature, and not all compilers have caught up yet.

According to [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) *GCC* supports it since *4.7*, *Clang* since *3.0*, and *MSVC* since *Nov 2012 CTP*.

Comment: I'm using a cmake make file.  Is there a certain setting I should be setting?

Comment: @will It's not about the makefile, it's about the compiler.

Comment: right, just no matter what I put in the cmake file to generate the make file, it won't work, so I'm just going to break the initialization into its own function and have all of the constructors call it.